# Preorder tree traversal using postorder + inorder

Tags: java, recursion, tree, traversal, preorder

Hello I'm working on printing preorder tree traversal only having inorder and postorder traversal. Code to do that looks like :

```
   public static void preorder( int inorder[], int inostart, int postorder[], int poststart, int length)
    {
      if(length==0) return; //terminating condition
      int k=0;
      System.out.print(postorder[length-1] + " ");

      for(int i=inostart; i<inostart+length; i++)
      {
        if(postorder[poststart+length-1]==inorder[i])
        {
          k=i;
          break;
        }
      }
      preorder(inorder, inostart, postorder, poststart, poststart+k-(inostart+1)); 
      preorder(inorder, inostart+k-poststart+1, postorder, k+1, length-k+inostart-1);
    }
```

but I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2` for testing numbers

POSTORDER

4 2 7 5 9 8 6 3 1

INORDER
4 2 1 5 7 3 6 8 9

Comment: If your binary tree implementation does not allow duplicates, then your post-order and in-order traversal results do not even look right

Comment: there are no duplicates

Comment: You should re-examine your postorder and inorder implementations again, 4 can't be both the root node and the left leaf node at the same time, and yes I know my comments are off topic

Comment: I don't have postorder and inorder implementation ? there is just this function to get preorder traversal and inside my main function I give to it inorder and postorder numbers